# Singular Cohomology vs de Rham cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

I try to compute $H^p_{dR}(\mathbb{C}P^n, \mathbb{C})$, using Mayer-Vietoris sequence, i know how to compute $H^p_{dR}(\mathbb{C}P^n, \mathbb{R})$, but i am stuck in this situation how to pass from $\mathbb{R}$-coefficient to $\mathbb{C}$-coefficient. De Rham cohomology in almost every textbook that i look at defined on real valued $p$-form. Is there any way to compute directly on $H^p_{dR}(\mathbb{C}P^n,\mathbb{C})$?

is it true that $H^p(\mathbb{C}P^n,\mathbb{C})=H^p_{dR}(\mathbb{C}P^n, \mathbb{R})\otimes \mathbb{C}$ for any $p$? if it is true, how can i prove it?

Comment: Any proof you've done with real-valued differential forms will work verbatim with complex-valued differential forms.

Comment: i am so privileged to get response from you dear Sir whom i learned many concepts about calculus. Thank You Sir.